# Deserializing JSON to Java using Jackson

Tags: java, json, deserialization, pojo, json-deserialization

I am working with JSON for the very first time and I am trying to deserialise a JSON file into Java objects.

**InputJSON**

```
{

    "student_id" : "123",
     "courses":[
        {
         "course_id":"789",
         "professor":"abc"
        }
      ]
}
{
    "student_id":"234",
     courses:[
       {
         "course_id":"789",
         "professor":"pqr"
       },
       {
         "course_id":"789",
         "professor":"xyz"
       }
     ]
}
{
   "student_id" : "345",
     "courses":[
        {
         "course_id":"567",
         "professor":"lmn"
        }
      ]
}
```

**Student.class**

```
class Student {

   @JsonProperty("student_id")
   private String studentId;
   @JsonProperty("courses")
   private List<Courses> courses;

   //getters and setters

}
```

**Courses.class**

```
public class Courses {

    @JsonProperty("course_id")
    private String courseId;
    @JsonProperty("professor")
    private String professor;

    //getters and setters
}
```

My **JsonHelper.class** creates an object of Object Mapper class and uses readValue(new File("Input.json"),Student.class) to to map the json fields to Java objects.

What I want to do is create a map with studentId as a key and the list of courses as the value corresponding to each studentId.

I am not exactly getting how to achieve it since my list is just able to get 1 element and the list size is thus 1. And issue with creating the map too. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This java class seems wrong. because your variable name is not the same with your JSON object.

```
public class Courses {
    @JsonProperty("course_id")
    private String courseId;
    @JsonProperty("professor")
    private String professor;
    //getters and setters
}
```

it would be like this,

```
class Student {
   @JsonProperty("student_id")
   private String student_id;
   @JsonProperty("courses")
   private List<Courses> courses;
   //getters and setters

    }
    public class Courses {
            @JsonProperty("course_id")
            private String course_id;
            @JsonProperty("professor")
            private String professor;
            //getters and setters
        }
```

Comment: I think the variable names aren't a problem here since the mapping is being done by annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to do mapping with ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

For parsing a single Student object:

```
Student student = objectMapper.readValue(inputJSONString, Student.class);
```

For parsing a list of Student object which is what you want:

```
List<Student> students = objectMapper.readValue(inputJSONString, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Student.class));
```

For parsing a maps:

```
Map<String, Courses> maps = objectMapper.readValue(inputJSONString, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, Courses.class));
```

Comment: I feel my language was a bit ambiguous in the question. So what I am actually trying to create is a Map with each student id.  So there is just one student object. It has a map wherein the keys are student ids and the values are the corresponding list of courses.

Comment: I have just updated my answer. For specific case, you can adjust the way of using objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructType... Some might apply, some might not. You need to give it a try for your specific purpose. From my point, the list parsing is what you need in this case.